# Show alert message to the desired VC from method in another VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I implemented this in my ***GatewayManager.m***

```
+ (void)GetAPIName:(NSString *)APIName
     withParameter:(NSMutableDictionary *)parameter
     returnManager:(void(^)(AFHTTPSessionManager *manager))returnManager
          progress:(void(^)(NSProgress *uploadProgress))progress
           success:(void(^)(NSDictionary *result))success
             error:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure {

    if([ShareFunction isInternetConnecting] && [ShareFunction isVPNConnected]) {
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kServerDomain, APIName];
        if (![APIName isEqualToString:kAccountLogin]) {
            [parameter setObject:[UserManager shareInstance].token forKey:@"accessToken"];
        }
        [manager GET:urlString
          parameters:parameter
            progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
                progress(downloadProgress);
            } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"[API] %@ Success : %@",APIName, responseObject);
                success(responseObject);

            } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                NSLog(@"[API] %@ Error : %@",APIName, error);
                failure(error);
                //NSLog(@"[API] %@ Error : %@",APIName, error);
            }];
    } else {
        [ShareFunction showSimpleAlertWithString:@"Internet/VPN no connect" inVC:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];

        failure(nil);
    }

}
```

I have a problem with this line

```
[ShareFunction showSimpleAlertWithString:@"Internet/VPN no connect" inVC:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
```

If it's root VC who calls this method, there's no problem to show the alert message on that VC. **But if it's not root VC, how can I show the alert message on that VC?**

Comment: Why don't you make use of protocols or completion blocks to achieve the same :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari can you show me some code please? I'm not sure what you mean. Please bear with me I'm quite new.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this

```
[ShareFunction showSimpleAlertWithString:@"Internet/VPN no connect" inVC:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
```

with

```
[ShareFunction showSimpleAlertWithString:@"Internet/VPN no connect"];
```

Comment: Please see my updated question. There's method called + `(void)showSimpleAlertWithString:(NSString*)string inVC:(UIViewController *)vc` so it won't allow.